# Trouble with Pandas Spearman Correlation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, correlation

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_csv('xxx.csv')
df = df.dropna()
df.head()
spearmancorr = df.corr(method = 'spearman')
spearmancorr
```

**

For some reason I get a '__' as the output... it also says that I have an empty dataframe (but df.head()) shows that this clearly isn't the case?

Comment: Can you post a sample dataframe. Make sure the `dtypes` of the columns are numeric (int or float) and not object.

Comment: ah problem solved! thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use [pd.DataFrame.corr](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html), the `dtypes` of the columns must be numeric - i.e. either `int` or `float`.